# How do I continuously re-run a program in Python?

Tags: python, loops

I created a program that calculates how much money is saved after a "percentage off" is applied.  The user is able to input the price of the product as well as the percentage off.  After the program does the calculation, how do I continuously loop the program so that the user can keep using it without me having to click "run" each time in the console.

```
def percent_off_price():
    price = amount * percent

    amount = float(input('Enter the price of your product: '))
    percent = float(input('Enter the percentage off: '))
    price = amount * percent
    print('You will save $',price,'off!  Your total is: $',amount - price,)
```

Comment: Try researching about `loops`...

Comment: How many times would you want it to loop (repeat)? How would your program know when to stop asking and not repeat infinitely? A `loop` will solve your problem, however consider the answers to my first two sentences before constructing one.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the whole code segment in a while loop which runs always but it is the worst thing you would want:

```
while True:      
    amount = float(input('Enter the price of your product: '))
    percent = float(input('Enter the percentage off: '))
    price = amount * percent
    print('You will save $',price,'off!  Your total is: $',amount - price,)
```

You can also put a check to run it for controlled amount. Hence it would only run if the amount entered is a positive value:

```
flag= True    
while flag:      
    amount = float(input('Enter the price of your product: '))
    if amount <0:
        flag=False
    percent = float(input('Enter the percentage off: '))
    price = amount * percent
    print('You will save $',price,'off!  Your total is: $',amount - price,)
```

Lastly if you want to run it for a fixed no. of times (Let's say 10) you can go for a for loop:

```
for i in range(10):      
    amount = float(input('Enter the price of your product: '))
    percent = float(input('Enter the percentage off: '))
    price = amount * percent
    print('You will save $',price,'off!  Your total is: $',amount - price,)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
while True:
  percent_off_price()
```

Comment: He can do alot of things. But why should he do that?